# Multiprocessing for a range of loops in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a very big array that I need to create with over 10^7 columns that needs to get filtered/modified depending on some criteria. There is a set of 24 different criterias (2x4x3 due to combinations) which means the filtering/modification needs to be done 24 times and each result is saved in a different specified directory.

Since this takes a very long time, I am looking into using multiprocessing to speed up the process. Can anyone help me out? Here is an exemplary code:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

sample_size = 1000000
variables = 25
x_array = np.random.rand(variables, sample_size)
      
x_dir = ['x1', 'x2']
y_dir = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']  
z_dir = ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']

x_directories = [0, 1]
y_directories = [0, 1, 2, 3]
z_directories = [0, 1, 2]

directory_combinations = itertools.product(x_directories, y_directories, z_directories)

for k, t, h in directory_combinations:

    target_dir=main_dir+'/'+x_dir[k]+'/'+y_dir[t]+'/'+z_dir[h]

    for i in range(sample_size):

        #x_array gets filtered/modified 
    
    #x_array gets saved in target_dir directory as a dataframe after modification'''
```

Basically with multiprocessing I am hoping for either each loop handled by a single core out of 16 I have available or for each loop iteration to be sped up by using all 16 cores.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are only creating a single array, then currently each iteration of the loop iteratively modifies the array and you are then writing out each new version to a different file. But if you run this in parallel, you could have multiple processes finishing at the same time and each would be saving out identical files with the same two sets of changes. Have you thought about this? This would prohibit you from sharing a single copy of the array (in shared memory) among all the processes. (more...)

Comment: But you can't pass to each invocation of your function a separate copy of the the array. Not only would this be costly memory wise, but each invocation would not be seeing the changes made by previous invocations. So how can you replicate what you are currently doing in parallel?

Comment: And how does the array get filtered/modified each time.? Nothing you posted shows how each of the 24 times varies from one another or might or might not depend on a previous filter/modification. Your `for i in range(sample_size):` does not appear to be very realistic but suggests that each modification depends on a previous modification. These things matter and determine whether your problem can even be parallelized. And if each modification iteration depends on a previous modification iteration, this cannot be parallelized.

Comment: Thanks for asking these.

Basically in the original code the big array I create outside the loop gets copied inside the loop (np.copy) and while iterating over the columns (sample_size) certain columns get deleted in the copied array. The deletion is based on a criteria that is unique in every loop. I load a different criteria array from the target_dir in every loop for this. At the end of every loop the copied array with a lesser number of columns gets saved as a dataframe in the specified target directory.

Comment: So the starting array is always the same for every loop. But as you mentioned I can see why this could create some memory problems when parallelizing the problem. Would you have any useful suggestions here?

Comment: Didn't you think these details might be important? In this case you *can* parallelize the code since each iteration seems to be independent of one another. The only issue is that since each iteration requires its own copy and you will be running 12 iterations in parallel, this could put a strain on memory. Depending on how much storage you have, you might want to reduce the pool size.

Answer (score 0):

Take one of loop and rewrite it to function

```
for k, t, h in directory_combinations:
```

Becomes for example

```
def func(k,t,h):
....
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(12)
pool.starmap_async(func, directory_combinations, 32)
```

It spawns 12 processes, that apply func on each iteration of  2 argument. Data tranfered to processes by 32-length chunks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. So if I understand correctly this will use 12 CPU cores and each core will be responsible for two sets of k, t, h iterations? Why is it important that the data is transferred to each process by 32-length chunks?

Comment: 32-length is for example purpose. You can use bigger chunks or not use it. Without this parameter process breaks after each iteration for receive new value of (k,t,h). With chunk it receives [(k,t,h),(k,t,h)....32-(k,t,h)] and works alone.

Comment: Hi again, thanks I think I am starting to get it. I realised I've made a mistake when I created the post - there are 24 diffrerent criterias.

I've rewritten the code in the following way:

`import multiprocessing 
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(k, t, h):
...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(12)
    pool.starmap_async(func, directory_combinations, 24)`

However nothing really happens when I execute the code. The function definitely works. so I don't know where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

The following code first creates the `x_array` in shared memory and initialized each process in the pool with global variable `x_array`, which is this shared array.

I would move the code that creates a the copy of this global `x_array`, processes it and then writes out the `dataframe` to a function, `worker`, which is passed the target directory as an argument.

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import multiprocessing as mp

SAMPLE_SIZE = 1000000
VARIABLES = 25

def to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape):
    '''Create a numpy array backed by a shared memory Array.'''
    arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array)
    return arr.reshape(shape)

def to_shared_array(arr, ctype):
    shared_array = mp.Array(ctype, arr.size, lock=False)
    temp = np.frombuffer(shared_array, dtype=arr.dtype)
    temp[:] = arr.flatten(order='C')
    return shared_array

def init_pool(shared_array, shape):
    global x_array
    # Recreate x_array using shared memory array:
    x_array = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)

def worker(target_dir):
    # make copy of x_array with np.copy
    x_array_copy = np.copy(x_array)
    for i in range(sample_size):
        #x_array_copy gets filtered/modified
        ...

    #x_array_copy gets saved in target_dir directory as a dataframe after modification

def main(): 
    main_dir = '.' # for example

    x_dir = ['x1', 'x2']
    y_dir = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']
    z_dir = ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']

    x_directories = [0, 1]
    y_directories = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    z_directories = [0, 1, 2]

    directory_combinations = itertools.product(x_directories, y_directories, z_directories)
    target_dirs =  [main_dir+'/'+x_dir[k]+'/'+y_dir[t]+'/'+z_dir[h] for k, t, h in directory_combinations]

    x_array = np.random.rand(VARIABLES, SAMPLE_SIZE)
    shape = x_array.shape
    # Create array in shared memory
    shared_array = to_shared_array(x_array, ctypes.c_int64)
    # Recreate x_array using the shared memory array as the base:
    x_array = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)

    # Create pool of 12 processes copying the shared array to each process:
    pool = mp.Pool(12, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(shared_array, shape))

    pool.map(worker, target_dirs)

# This is required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I have no idea why I put the big array in the loop. 
The big array is actually created outside the loop and the same big array is modified inside the loop according to different criteria and the result gets saved at the end.

Comment: Then whoever upvoted your question should have downvoted it. You should edit your question.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your new description.

Comment: Many thanks. I will have a go at it soon.